# Will these variables live throughout the life time of the main frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter program. The main class is `MainFrame()`

```
class MainFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        # sets up the tab bar
        self.tabbar = TabBar(self, 'File Tabe Bar')
        self.tabs = []
        self.add_tab(self.tabbar, 'Hello Tab') # add a new tab to self.tabs
        self.tabbar.pack()  # make it visible

    def add_tab(self, parent, name='Default'):
        tab = Tab(parent, name)
        self.tabs.append(tab)
```

Will each of the `tab` variable created by invoking `add_tab` persist throughout the life time of the main frame (until it is destroyed)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each variable is bind to an object `Tab`. Each `Tab` has a parent. The variable local to the function will be gone once the function exists - that is, the binding is lost, but you have the reference to the object `Tab` (each of them) in the list `self.tabs` which persist throughout the life time of the object `MyFrame`.

Each object `Tab` will live until the parent class (and / or  the parents of the parent class) are destroyed (or by invoking a destroy method on `Tab`)

Just my wild guess ::(